# SharePoint 2013 Document Organization

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to find a better way to organize a huge mass of documents on SharePoint 2013. I've done a lot of searching and I thought that Enterprise Metadata would be my solution but I have yet to find a good way to harness it. I fell like there must be a solution to what I need built into to SharePoint already.

I want to give each document a "tag" or Enterprise Metadata Keyword and then have a document library that only displays files that are associated with a specific keyword. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a pretty broad question for Stack Overflow. Maybe you can explain what options you have tried and what isn't working about them?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest some built-in SharePoint document library features to consider to start with, before looking at any third-party offerings.

For a document library, (via the settings for the document library), you can enable *Metadata Navigation Settings* - this can allow a user to filter list items based on metadata fields. This may offer something along the lines of what you described. I'd advise caution for large lists though.

Another option would be to look at creating or amending views for the library - the options are found on the  *Library* tab of the ribbon. You can setup some filtering or aggregration for the view.

There is also the option, if appropriate to make certain views only available at specific locations within the document library - set via the *per-location view settings*